# How to wait on the client side until connection to mongo on the server side is ready?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a kind of slow connection between my meteor server and remote mongodb instance. Can I somehow wait on a client side and not register subscriptions until the server is not established connection to mongo?

Comment: You should edit your question if you have an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One primitive way of doing this is listening for a change in Meteor.userId() using Meteor.autorun. If you are able to get this, you would know that you have connected to MongoDB. If you are not dealing with authentication, then you could create a method on the server side which returns something from MongoDB. When it returns something, on success in the client side you could start all of the subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, this is the most useful and easy way to do it.

Comment: There should be a better way of checking for Mongo readiness but I don't think its on the priority list for Meteor right now.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way of doing this is via a Meteor.call invocation. If you do this as a synchronous call (no callback), the client will wait until the call completes. Here's how to do it asynchronously:

```
  Meteor.call('isEverythingReady', param1,
    function(error, result) {
      if (error === undefined) {
        Meteor.subscribe("mystuff");
        Session.set("sess1", "whatever");
      } else {
        alert("There was an error during startup.");
      }
    });
```

and then

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods( {
    isEverythingReady: function(param1) {
      // can you connect to database?
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue on one of my projects in Meteor and this answer did work when I went through their docs and figured out myself how to do it. However you should probably list how to make the functions (Adding edit to your answer)

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment - the callback function is shown in the snippet above.

Comment: Well yeah but the function to call wasn't listed on how to create it, when I originally had tried this I tried to make a default function x() instead of a meteor.methods(). And as for the question in the comment, yes you can connect to the database that way.

Comment: you have a typo: `y` is missing in `isEverythingReady: function(param1)`. Stupid SO rule requires at least 6 character diff for me to be able to edit the answer.